# xPages Designer Team menu is missing

Tags: xpages

I was installing source control in the xPages / Domino designer and screwed it up.  In trying to repair my flawed install, I've somehow removed the "Team" designer menu option.

Can anyone tell me how to get the "Team" menu option in designer back?

Thanks in advance,

-- Jeff

Answer (score 0, accepted):

99% of the time, deleting the workspace folder will reset everything (back it up somewhere in case you need the stuff in it).

This will resolve issues caused by most broken plugins.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are in the package explorer because Team is only displayed there.
What I try is to do a reset perspective that can be found in the window menu.

Answer (score 0):

One thing that I wasted a lot of time on was not being able to find the "Team Development" menu in the Navigator pane (your "normal" Domino Designer view of databases). The trick is to select the XPages perspective... ;-)

/John