# Team Development menu option in IBM Lotus Domino Designer

Tags: xpages, lotus-domino, lotus

Is there a way to add the Team Development menu option to the Domino Development perspective in IBM Lotus Domino Designer?

Comment: ... or you may have a look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12602998/xpages-designer-team-menu-is-missing

/John

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found the answer. Go to Windows menu on DDE and select "Customize perspective". Switch to the "Commands" tab and in the "Available command groups" find "Domino Designer Team Development" and activate it.